# Get percentages of each values counted in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count, percentage

I have all lottery draws stored in a SQLite database.
I am using this query to count how many times numbers appears in last 150 draws to present:

```
SELECT LAST_150, COUNT(LAST_150) FROM CalculatedNumbers GROUP BY LAST_150 ORDER BY COUNT(LAST_150) DESC;
```

LAST_150 is a column in my table named CalculatedNumbers which store how many times a given number can be found in last 150 draws to the present.
It gives me this result:

[image]

**Which is read as follow**: In last 150 drawn 18002 numbers are drawn 37 times. 17882 numbers are drawn just 38 times in Last 150 draws and so on.

How to do it to show another column which gets the percentages for each population of numbers. e.g. x% means 18002, x% means 17882, x% means 17352 from the total numbers count?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Sample data as text (Preferably as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements that can just be copy and pasted, or maybe CSV), and expected results of that sample would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select 
    last_150, 
    count(*) no_last_150,
    1.0 * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over () percent_last_150
from calculatednumbers 
group by last_150 
order by count(last_150) desc;
```

If your version of SQLite does not suport window functions, then:

```
select 
    last_150, 
    count(*) no_last_150,
    1.0 * count(*) / (select count(*) from calculatednumbers) percent_last_150
from calculatednumbers 
group by last_150 
order by count(last_150) desc;
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your solution because no matter what SQLite query I use it gives wrong percentages. e.g. for LAST_10 it shows this: https://i.imgur.com/JEsMczP.png as you can see from the table one single number is counted 10 times in the last 10 draws and it shows the biggest percentages for it instead to be the smallest one. Also, for 69583 it shows the smallest percentage instead the biggest one. Thank you in advance!